# HighCharts does not render color in bar graph

Tags: jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I am just learning how to use javascript and ASP.NET. I would like to use HighCharts and am experiencing a rendering problem. I have looked through the questions on here and many of them seem to be not related to my problem, that I can tell.

This is the code for my specific view.

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Summary";
}

@section HeadContent{
<script src="../../Scripts/HighCharts/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/HighCharts/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Code Coverage Per Baseline'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [11.5, 12.5],

                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right'
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,

                title: {
                    text: 'Coverage Percentage ( % )'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '' + this.x + ":" + this.y;
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,

                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Function Coverage',
                data: [12, 82]
                }, {
                    name: 'Condition Coverage',
                    data: [74, 32]
                }]
        });

    });

</script>

}

@section Toolbar
{
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("<< Back to Summary", "Index")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}

<h2>Summary Information</h2>
<div id="container" style="width: 860px; height: 400px; text-align: center"></div>
```

In my _Layout.cshtml file I reference these..

```
@RenderSection("HeadContent", false)
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js")
```

I have tried changing the color, moving around the javascript, and using jsFiddle to check my code. Nothing seems to be changing it.

Since I don't have enough reputation I can't post a screen shot inside of here so I'll explain. [image: *Link to picture*]

What happens is that I go to the specific view through the site and loads the graph fine, but the only thing that doesn't appear is the color of the bars. I can select them and it shows what their values are. When I go into chrome's debugger I am able to highlight and look at the generated source code for each bar. The only problem is that the fill="rgb(192,192,192)" and fill-opacity="0.000001". This is part of the problem. Not sure why they are being set to a default grey color with basically 0 opacity. (All visible in the link above)

It would be great if anyone has encountered this before or might know of a couple of things to check. Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

[image: Would this be a potential problem?] Where it seems like other scripts are being run at after the body is created? Could there be a javascript rendering problem?

EDIT* - I forgot to mention that when I export the graph to png or jpeg, the colors are there and it renders fine. Not sure if this helps, but I just think I am missing something very small.

Comment: [Here is the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjH3w/)

Comment: Are you seeing the problem in the fiddle you posted?  It renders fine for me.

Comment: I used the fiddle to validate that my javascript will render. All I change is the first two lines of the javascript so that I can run it in fiddle.

Comment: So you need to change color of fill for serie or point ?

Comment: Yea, the defaults shouldn't be set to that though. I know they aren't because when I highlight the columns, it knows what color it is just doesn't display it.